# Screen shot in power menu

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

On a previous phone, the HTC One X,  I had the print screen option show up in the power menu. It was along side shut down,  restart,  etc..

I now have the Vodafone Smart 6 Ultra but I can't find any settings relating to the feature I want.

Is it possible to add the screenshot menu option without rooting my device?

Comment: Similar but unanswered question: [Can I change or add to the power off menu in Android 5.1?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/104892)

Comment: Does this help http://www.techmuzz.com/how-to/android/add-screenshot-option-in-the-power-menu-in-lollipop/